# How to DRY inside activities

Tags: java, android

In all activities in my project, I am hiding the status bar and doing more of these activity-related things (that all my activities have in common). There is the function I prepared for hiding the status bar:

```
void hideStatusBar()
{
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

How do I perform this function (and not only this one) in every activity I have, without copy-pasting the function to every activity (to not violate DRY)?

Comment: Use a superclass, and put this method in it. Then make all your activities extend the superclass

Comment: @SuperStormer IMO Inheritance is a really poor way to apply characteristics like this to multiple implementations. In Java you can only extend a single class, and if some activities need to differ in characteristics, then you need to create multiple base classes. This ends up causing the same types of duplication and a complex inheritance structure. You should really favor composition when applying characteristics like this, and IMO even a simple static utility method will provide you with more flexibility than class extension.

Comment: Good point @flakes,

Comment: That is the problem I was aware of - as @flakes mentioned - you can not extend more classes. His solution posted below seems good for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create this as a static utility method.

```
public final class ActivityUtils {
    private ActivityUtils() {}

    public static void hideStatusBar(final Activity activity) {
        activity.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        activity.getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}
```

Usage from the activity would look like `ActivityUtils.hideStatusBar(this)`

Alternatively you can extract this method signature to an interface, and inject this logic into your activity. This will be helpful if you ever want some activities to use slightly different versions of status hiding.

```
public interface StatusBarHider {
    void hideStatusBar(final Activity activity);
}

public class DefaultStatusBarHider implements StatusBarHider {
    @Override
    public void hideStatusBar(final Activity activity) {
        activity.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        activity.getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}

// ex; Possibly Guice or Dagger for injection
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Inject
    private StatusBarHider hider;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your changes are related to the visual aspect of your activities, you could specify everything in you AppTheme on styles.xml

To hide the status bar, for example, you would use:

```
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

Then all activities using your theme will look the same

Answer (score 0):

```
private void showSystemUI() {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }

private void hideSystemUI() {
    // Enables regular immersive mode.
    // For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.
    // Or for "sticky immersive," replace it with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                    // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
                    // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```